# How to sort the order of index for value_counts() to a custom order?

Tags: python, pandas

After performing value_counts() to a series in a dataframe,

```
>>> n_fires_by_month = df['month'].value_counts()
>>> n_fires_by_month
```

I get this:

```
| -------| -------------- |
| aug    | 184            |
| sep    | 172            |
| mar    | 54             |
| jul    | 32             |
| feb    | 20             |
| jun    | 17             |
| oct    | 15             |
| dec    | 9              |
| apr    | 9              |
| may    | 2              |
| jan    | 2              |
| nov    | 1              |
```

After running `value_counts()`, I want to reset the index of the resulting table in order of `month` so I want the resulting table to look like this:

```
| -------| -------------- |
| jan    | 2              |
| feb    | 20             |
| mar    | 54             |
| apr    | 9              |
| may    | 2              |
| jun    | 17             |
| jul    | 32             |
| aug    | 184            |
| sep    | 172            |
| oct    | 15             |
| nov    | 1              |
| dec    | 9              |
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Using the days' abbreviations from the module `calendar`, *reindex* the dataframe. No explicit sorting is needed:

```
abbr_months = [x.lower() for x in calendar.month_abbr][1:]
df.set_index('month').reindex(abbr_months)
#jan    2
#feb   20
#mar   54
#apr    9
#may    2
#jun   17
#jul   32
#aug  184
#sep  172
#oct   15
#nov    1
#dec    9
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search, I found this:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/pandas+value_counts+sort

So this should work for you:

**n_fires_by_month = df['month'].value_counts().sort_index()**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the months to a `datetime` object and then sort like this:

```
df['month_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%b')
df = df.sort_values(by='month_dt')
```

Output:

```
    month   Count   month_dt
10  jan     2      1900-01-01
4   feb     20     1900-02-01
2   mar     54     1900-03-01
8   apr     9      1900-04-01
9   may     2      1900-05-01
5   jun     17     1900-06-01
3   jul     32     1900-07-01
0   aug     184    1900-08-01
1   sep     172    1900-09-01
6   oct     15     1900-10-01
11  nov     1      1900-11-01
7   dec     9      1900-12-01
```